# How to delete an entry from an array in Java so that the other entries remain in order

Tags: java, arrays

Forgive the clunky title

I want to write a method that removes a specific entry from an array, but doesn't leave a null gap in the array. For example if a String array contained

```
|aa,bb,cc,dd,ee|
```

the user would be prompted to enter which number they wanted removed, the method would find the index of that entry, remove that index, then move the null entry to the last slot.

So if the user entered cc, the array's contents would be

```
|aa,bb,dd,ee,null|
```

EDIT: I realized I left out some information here. the entry I'm looking to remove will be passed from another method. I will then use a for loop to find the index of the entry (If not found nothing is done). However I'm stuck on how to do the deletion.

Comment: The Array is used in other methods, and I can't rewrite the whole program. That's why I need to make it so the non-null entries are the first ones, because that's what the other methods are expecting.

Comment: I would be, it's not a possibility in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this maybe:

```
for (int i = index; i < array.length -1; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i+1];
}
array[array.length - 1] = null;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was a simpler way of doing it

Answer (score 6):

First of all: I strongly suggest to use an `ArrayList` where you can easily remove and add items without having to change the rest of the collection (it also has a `toArray()` method).

That being said, tihs would be a sample solution to do it with just arrays:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] arr = new String[5];
    arr[0] = "aa";
    arr[1] = "bb";
    arr[2] = "cc";
    arr[3] = "dd";
    arr[4] = "ee";

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    int deleteIndex = 2;        
    System.arraycopy(arr, deleteIndex + 1, arr, deleteIndex, arr.length - deleteIndex - 1);
    arr[4] = null;

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Output:

> [aa, bb, cc, dd, ee]
>   [aa, bb, dd, ee, null]

The idea is to to shift the elements one place ahead starting from the index to delete + 1. Afterwards you set the latest item manually to `null` or it will duplicate the last entry.

Answer (score 0):

To keep the contents in order as you remove you need to **shift elements** to the left of the array.
The most naive and wasteful way would be to initialize another array with 1 size less than the current.
Then copy all the elements in a loop from your array but **not** the one that the user wants to remove (jumping that index)

Comment: Is there a simpler way to shift elements?

Comment: @Spork:Shifting is the most efficient.You can alway go for the second approach that requires more space

Answer (score 0):

You have the gist of it in your description

> the user would be prompted to enter which number they wanted removed, the method would find the index of that entry, remove that index, then move the null entry to the last slot.

with not writing the actual code, since this seems like a school assignment, I'll just add what happens to the indexes of the rest of the entries after the deleted index?

Comment: They should be shifted to the left one. I was unsure how to do that.

Comment: Yes, i was just trying to imply what happens to the actual index numbers when you're shifting to the left (like 3 becomes 2, 4 will become 3, basically subtract one for each) but there are also examples people have written above

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make the array into a List, remove the entry then make it into an array again.

```
ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
aList.remove(yourIndex);
return aList.toArray(new String[yourArray.length]);
```

As a Test example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] yourArray = new String[]{"FF","AA","BB"};
    for(String s : yourArray)
        System.out.println(s);

    System.out.println("");

    ArrayList<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(yourArray));
    aList.remove(1);
    String[] r = aList.toArray(new String[yourArray.length]);

    for(String s : r)
        System.out.println(s);

}
```

Output

```
FF
AA
BB

FF
BB
null
```